# Default string type values in typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type PredefinedStrings = 'test' | 'otherTest';

interface MyObject {
    type: string | PredefinedStrings;
}
```

The `MyObject` interface should have a single `type` property, which could be either one of the `PredefinedStrings` or a string that was defined somewhere along the line by the developer.

What I would like to achieve with this, is to let the developer type in any string as the `type` property (this is achieved by the above code), BUT also show the predefined types as an IntelliSense suggestion when starting to provide the value for the `type` property.

Is there any way to achieve both of the above requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), which seems to be the builtin to do what you want:

```
enum Tests {
    Test = 'test',
    OtherTest = 'otherTest'
}
```

This should allow Intellisense to autocomplete the `enum` values.

Answer (score 0):

Some addition to @kabanus answer:

Also, to achieve completely what you want, you can define `MyObject` as generic:

```
interface MyObject<T extends string> {
  type: T | PredefinedStrings;
}
```

After that consumer of your interface will be able to define its own type like this:

```
enum SomeEnum {
  TYPE1 = "TYPE1",
  TYPE2 = "TYPE2",
}

type ExtendedMyObject = MyObject<SomeEnum>;
```